# Converting subquery to join assistance

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am my subquery is severely slowing my full query down in MySQL.  I'm in the process of converting the original query to work on MySQL as I'm moving away from SQL Server where it has worked wonderfully.  MySQL on the other hand isnt too happy.  Was wondering if anyone could assist in helping me with a conversion solution to a join as I'm not well versed in joins quite yet.  Thanks!

```
select a.crm_ticket_details_detail, 
        crm_ticket_created_date, 
        crm_ticket_id, 
        crm_ticket_customer_id, 
        c.crm_assigned_user
              from php_crm.crm_ticket, 
                php_crm.crm_ticket_details a, 
                php_crm.crm_assigned c
              where crm_ticket_resolved_date is null
              and crm_ticket_id = a.crm_ticket_details_ticket_id
              and a.crm_ticket_details_type = 'issue'
              and c.crm_assigned_ticket_id = crm_ticket_id
              and c.crm_assigned_id = (select max(d.crm_assigned_id) 
                                        from php_crm.crm_assigned d 
                                        where d.crm_assigned_ticket_id = crm_ticket_id)
```

Comment: is just the subquery with the max(d.crm_assigned_id) slowing down your query?
if so, is there an index on crm_assigned_id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 details.crm_ticket_details_detail,
 CT.crm_ticket_created_date,
 CT.crm_ticket_id,
 CT.crm_ticket_customer_id,
 ASSIGNED.crm_assigned_user
FROM
 php_crm.crm_ticket CT (NONAME)
 INNER JOIN php_crm.crm_ticket_details DETAILS -- (A)
  ON CT.crm_ticket_id = DETAILS.crm_ticket_details_ticket_id 
 INNER JOIN php_crm.crm_assigned ASSIGNED -- (C)
  ON CT.crm_ticket_id = ASSIGNED.crm_assigned_ticket_id 
WHERE
 crm_ticket_resolved_date IS NULL 
 AND DETAILS.crm_ticket_details_type = 'issue' 
 AND 
 AND ASSIGNED.crm_assigned_id = (SELECT
                       max(d.crm_assigned_id)
                      FROM
                       php_crm.crm_assigned d
                      WHERE
                       d.crm_assigned_ticket_id = crm_ticket_id)
```

I believe that's what you're looking for. I can't speak to whether it will actually improve performance, although it will certainly make it easier to understand. I'm not sure the old style of joins is actually less efficient; just harder to read / easier to make product joins with.

That said, if there are other common keys between the three tables that are being indirectly neutralized in other parts of the logic then that could have a performance impact.

(EDIT: Actually not sure if this was what you're looking for, reread your question and you seem focused on the subquery... I don't see any problems jumping out with that, would need more details to address that.)